# What is the MySQL equivalent of SQL Server's UPDATE() trigger function?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

I need help converting this MS SQL update trigger to MySQL.  My problem is with converting the MS SQL [UPDATE() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which identifies the specific columns that were updated:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tran_upd_action] ON [dbo].[tran_action]
FOR UPDATE AS

BEGIN
   IF @@ROWCOUNT>0
     BEGIN
        IF update(column1) OR update(column2)
          BEGIN
             INSERT into tran_indexerqueue 
                (trankey, trkey2, tranname) SELECT tran_actionid, 0, 'tranaction' from inserted
         END
    END
 END
```

Comment: Another thing you need to keep in mind: In SQL Server triggers are always fired **per statement**, whereas in MySQL they are fired **per row** (and not under all circumstances). To find out if a column was updated, I guess you need to compare the `old` and `new` values

Comment: There is no equivalent in MySQL's limited implementation of triggers, so following the advice of @a_horse_with_no_name is the only way I know of. This question essentially asks the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008656/get-current-updated-column-name-to-use-in-a-trigger

Comment: The update function in MS SQL tests whether an attempt was made to update the column.  So the update function sets to true whether a change was made or not.  The new value vs old value test means it would only fire if a change was actually made.

Comment: So this:  `code`IF UPDATE(column1) OR update(column2) THEN `code`    To This:   `code`IF ( Old.column1 <> New.column1) || (Old.column2 <> New.column2) THEN `code`.  Should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have the rowcount check, but the basic trigger syntax will be like this.  Note that only the Super User role can create a trigger.  Also, you have to change the delimiter first, which is usually a big gotcha for MSSQL DBAs.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `tran_upd_action` AFTER UPDATE ON `tran_action` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO tran_indexerqueue 
            (trankey, trkey2, tranname)
VALUES(OLD.trankey, OLD.trkey2, OLD.tranname);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: "*only the Super User role can create a trigger*". That is not true.

Comment: From the MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual...

"In MySQL 5.0 CREATE TRIGGER requires the SUPER privilege." 

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: But 5.0 is quite outdated. This restriction does not apply to 5.1 or later.

Comment: Noted, and thank you.  Always thought it was buggy that restores did not create the triggers unless you were the equiv of root.